# Discord JS MessageSelectMenu

Tags: discord.js

I would like to add an option to an existing MessageSelectMenu that I created like this:

```js
button = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
    new MessageSelectMenu()
        .setCustomId('selects')
        .setPlaceholder('Test')
        .addOptions([
            {
                label: 'test1',
                value: '1',
            },
        ])
)
```

For example, I would like to add this option:

```js
{
    label: 'test2',
    value: '2',
},
```

I can't do it.

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

To make **Discord Select Menus** you can follow:

```js
      const button = new MessageActionRow()
     .addComponents(
     new MessageSelectMenu()
    .setCustomId('selects')
      .setPlaceholder('Test')
       .addOptions([
       {
           label: 'test1',
           description: 'This is a description',
           value: '1',
           },
 // if you want to add another option in THIS menu you can continue below:
 
   label: 'You can select me too',
           description: 'This is also a description',
           value: 'second_option',
               },
           ]),
       );
```

For receiving **Select Menus** attach an eventlistner to client you can use **Interaction.isSelectMenu()**

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isSelectMenu()) return;
    if(interaction.CustomId === 'selects'){
      await interaction.update('selected')
    }
 });
```